# Lattices and Elliptic curves and number fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, integer-lattices

Let $K$ be a number field with ring of integers $O_K$.

If $K$ is totally real, then $O_K$ is a lattice in $\mathbb R$.

If $K$ is imaginary quadratic, then $O_K$ is a lattice in $\mathbb C$.

If $K$ is of degree $3$, then I want to consider $O_K$ as a lattice in $\mathbb C$. Is that possible?

Comment: The correct statement is that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^{r_1} \times \mathbb{C}^{r_2}$ where $r_1$ is the number of real embeddings and $2r_2$ is the number of complex embeddings. In the totally real case $r_1 = n$ is the degree of $K$.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "$O_K$ is a lattice in $\mathbb R$" when $K$ is totally real.

E.g. if $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$, then $O_K =\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ is abstractly isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^2$ as an abelian group, but it is dense
as a subset of $\mathbb R$ (so not one would normally call a lattice).

---

If the degree of $K$ is $d$, and $K$ has $r_1$ real embeddings and $2 r_2$ complex embeddings (so that $r_1 + 2 r_2 = d$), then $O_K$ may be regarded as a lattice
(i.e. a discrete copy of $\mathbb Z^d$) in $\mathbb R^{r_1} \times \mathbb C^{r_2}$.